# Looking for a better way of manipulating a numeric string that contains delimiters

Tags: javascript

I need to verify and manipulate a numeric string. In this example, I have this string `"1.59945,5|10"`. The `","` and `"|"` are delimiters, so it has three separate values: `1.59945`, `5` and `10`. I want to round off any float values (In this case `1.59945`) to the nearest 2 decimal places before saving the entire string back to the database. The result should be `"1.60,5|10"`.

Here's the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lau_chung/tkxp62vn/14/)

```
let values = "1.59945,5|10"
const separators = values.split("").filter(v=>{
  return v === "," || v=== "|"
})

const regex = new RegExp(`,|\\|`);
values = values.split(regex).map(value=>{
   if (value.includes(".")) {
      return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)
   } else {
      return value;
   }
}).join(",")
separators.forEach(separator=>{
   values = values.replace(",",separator)
})
console.log(values)
```

The code seems to achieve what I want, but is there a more concise / better way of doing it?

Comment: If you only care about the first `values.replace(/^([\d.]+)/,function(n){ return Number(n).toFixed(2); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple regular expression with replace can get rid of all the looping

```js
// If only the first is a float
const values = "1.59945,5|10"

console.log(values.replace(/^([\d.]+)/, function(n) {
  return Number(n).toFixed(2);
}));

// If any of them can be floats
const values2 = "1.59945,5.446|10";

console.log(values2.replace(/([\d.]+)/g, function(n) {
  return n.includes(".") ? Number(n).toFixed(2) : n;
}));
```

Comment: Using `.includes()` to filter out integers looks a bit odd. To focus on floats only, you need slightly more appropriate RegExp: `"1.59945,5|10".replaceAll(/\d+\.\d+/g, m => (+m).toFixed(2))`

Answer (score 1):

I think, we can do like this;

```
var string = "1.59945,5|10";
string.match(/\d+\.?\d*/).forEach((s) => { //Adjust your regex accordingly
  //you can add validation here also
  string = string.replace(s, parseFloat(s).toFixed(2));
});
console.log(string);
```